# refresh table after seach query android

Tags: android

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {

           addData(Transactionss);


        }
```

I have done a filter search whereby I would retrieve data for the query. But however, using the removeallviews function works only when there is no data to be found. When there is data that is found, it will show the data first but removing the query would see the data add to the preexisting data. [this is my table] 
Note : I do not have duplicate rows with same exact data

```
public void addData(ArrayList<Transactions> Transactions) {
   tl.removeAllViews();
```

Comment: Did you ever use notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: No but I am doing a table layout